# XGBoost discard trees that lead to a worsening in eval_metric on eval_set during training?

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm training an XGBoost model on some data as follows:

```
clf=xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=200,reg_lambda=100,colsample_bytree=0.8,learning_rate=0.02)
model=clf.fit(Xtrain.T,Ytrain[0,:],eval_set=[(Xtune.T,Ytune[0,:])],eval_metric=myMetric)
```

This produces `200` trees put together into a single XGB model. However, I see that during training several trees lead to a worse `eval_metric` result on the `eval_set` than before adding that tree.

I would like XGBoost to detect such worsening in `eval_metric` and discard that particular tree, and continue as before until a tree is found that actually leads to an improvement on the `eval_set`. I imagine that will lead to a creation of many more than `200` trees, many of which will be discarded.

Is there a way to do that with XGBoost? If so, what syntax should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I created the following quick and dirty workaround of continuing training a model for just one iteration and testing later if that iteration should be kept:

```
clf=xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1,reg_lambda=100,colsample_bytree=0.8,learning_rate=0.02,random_state=0)
mod=clf.fit(Xtrain.T,Ytrain[0,:],eval_set=[(Xtune.T,Ytune[0,:]),(Xtrain.T,Ytrain[0,:])],eval_metric=myMetric)
perf=mod.evals_result()['validation_0']['myMetric'][0]
cnt=1
for i in range(1000):
    clf=xgb.XGBRegressor(n_estimators=1,reg_lambda=100,colsample_bytree=0.8,learning_rate=0.02,random_state=i)
    mod2=clf.fit(Xtrain.T,Ytrain[0,:],eval_set=[(Xtune.T,Ytune[0,:]),(Xtrain.T,Ytrain[0,:])],eval_metric=myMetric,xgb_model=mod.get_booster())
    perf2=mod2.evals_result()['validation_0']['myMetric'][0]
    if perf2>perf:
        mod=mod2
        perf=perf2
        cnt=cnt+1
```

Still interested in an official solution!